# Trigger CloudWatch event on DynamoDB epoch field

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless

I'm looking for a way to trigger an event o AWS, on a specified time stored in DynamoDB. I was thinking whether it's possible. There is a TTL feature for DynamoDB which can trigger an event, but that results in data removal.

So right now I can use DynamoDB and remove data ( I want to preserve it)
or create CloudWatch event on DynamoDB update.

I don't like any of those, appreciate any input

Comment: What do you mean by "on a specified time stored in DynamoDB"?

Comment: There is option of specifying ttl in DynamoDB https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-before-you-start.html
So exactly same but not for purpose of removal data but invoking an event

Comment: You could find a way how to plug this together with DynamoDB (and Streams), but IMO that would be irrational. What don't you like about a scheduled Cloudwatch event?